# Capture letter group and repeat them certain times with the number in group

Tags: regex, go

I have string like: "R2(LF)3(PA)", and want to convert it to RLFLFPAPAPA (get rid of number and repeact the group of letters)

The idea come out is using regexp to capture the group, but I am stuck to get the result with code below, how can I solve that? Or I need to try other methods?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(move("R2(LF)3(PA)"))
}

func move(s string) string {

    rgx := regexp.MustCompile(`(\d)\((\w+)\)`)

    // code need here


    return s
}
```

Comment: This is Run Length [Encoding/Decoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), which is an algorithmic problem. Don't try to solve it with regexes

Comment: How are single repeating character encoded? e.g. `ABB` is done as `A2B` or `A2(B)`

Comment: only number and bracket parts need to process. `A2B` is illegal (without bracket) and `ABB` just leave alone @Inian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that *Go* doesn't have a replace function with a callback function (which is the most praticle case for us here). But I found [this implementation to do it](https://elliotchance.medium.com/go-replace-string-with-regular-expression-callback-f89948bad0bb).

So the idea is to convert the first group containing a string with the number to an integer value. Then we can repeat the group 2 containing the letters this number of times:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(move("R2(LF)3(PA)"))
}

func ReplaceAllStringSubmatchFunc(re *regexp.Regexp, str string, repl func([]string) string) string {
    result := ""
    lastIndex := 0
    for _, v := range re.FindAllSubmatchIndex([]byte(str), -1) {
        groups := []string{}
        for i := 0; i < len(v); i += 2 {
            groups = append(groups, str[v[i]:v[i+1]])
        }
        result += str[lastIndex:v[0]] + repl(groups)
        lastIndex = v[1]
    }
    return result + str[lastIndex:]
}

func move(s string) string {
    rgx := regexp.MustCompile(`(\d)\((\w+)\)`)
    return ReplaceAllStringSubmatchFunc(rgx, s, func(groups []string) string {
        // Convert the first group with the digits to an integer value.
        nbrTimes, err := strconv.Atoi(groups[1])
        if err != nil {
            // Handle error (could happen if very long number).
        }
        // Return the group 2 with the letters repeated n times.
        return strings.Repeat(groups[2], nbrTimes)
    })
}
```

You can run it online here: https://go.dev/play/p/FKNFJSc_tdS